# How to parallelize scipy optimizer?

Tags: python, scipy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to perform a multistart optimization using `for` loops (optimization is done using `scipy.optimize.minimize`).

```python
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def multistart optimizer(func, x):
    x_mins = []
    fvals = []
    n = x.shape[1]
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        optRes = minimize(func, x0 = x[i], bounds = ((0,1),)*n, tol = 1.e-6)
        x_mins.append(optRes.x)
        fvals.append(optRes.fun)
    fval = min(fvals)
    x_min = x_mins[np.argmin(fvals)]

    return x_min, fval
```

This works fine until when the size of initial starting points (`x`, in this case) increases and the time required to perform the `for` loop increases with it. Hence, I want to use multiple processors to speed things up in the `for` loop (since each loop is independent of one another, this should result the same thing).

I'm struggling to find just the right code. There were many examples involving the `multiprocessing` module, but I can't seem to understand how to implement them.

Another question is that all the examples seem to perform the parallelization within their code using `if __name__ == '__main__':`. I was wondering if this could be avoided and the parallel loop to run without it. To be more precise, if I have a loop that's defined in file `loop.py` and run this in multiple processors using `main.py` would it be possible?

Comment: You certainly can use multiple files.  The “spawn” start method puts (the same) restrictions on how to write the main script file however many you use.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if this could be avoided and the parallel loop to run without it. To be more precise, if I have a loop that's defined in file `loop.py` and run this in multiple processors using `main.py` would it be possible?

Yes, you can.

```python
class myThread(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, name):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.name = name
   def run(self):
      print "Starting " + self.name
```

You can create a subclass of `Thread`, then call it anywhere.

If you want to use model inside without re-initialize, save it as a static or global object.